# Display an image in a Popover Bootstrap with ruby code via Cloudinary/CarrierWave gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, carrierwave, popover, cloudinary

Hi it is my fourth question I ask in this template. Please could some one help me :)

I work on flashcard and I have to display an image in a popover when I trigger my cursor on it.

Here is my code

```
<div class="idea">
   <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-lg popover-img" 
   data-content=<%="#{cl_image_tag(@hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340)}"%>></i>
</div>
```

I put it in data content.

I used this javascript to call it in my layout/application.html.erb

```
<script >
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".popover-img").popover({
          html: true,
          trigger: "hover",
          // content: "",
          placement:'bottom'
        });
      })
```

The result is It cannot display the picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is the tag you're calling.  `cl_image_tag` is a helper which produces an `img` html tag.  But your js has the content line commented, so I'm guessing you've tried several thing.

If you choose to use a tag creator, and I understand why you would, it makes generated a size-based cloudinary url much simpler, then you'll need to escape that properly in single quotes in the data element, then call it and render the whole html tag in the js.

For instance I have something like this:

```
<span class="popover-trigger fa fa-4x fa-ban "
     data-toggle="popover"
     data-content='<%= cl_image_tag(current_user.avatar, 
        :width => 250, :height => 200) %>'></span>
```

And then your JS would look like:

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
  html: true,
  trigger: 'hover',
  content: function () {
    return $(this).data('content');
  }
});
```

That will call it on hover, and set the value in data-content attribute to render in the popover content area, as long as its properly quoted.

-- Based on your comments ---

I think your view code *might* look like:

```
<% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %> 

<div class="idea">
   <i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o fa-lg popover-img" 
   data-toggle="popover"
   data-content=<%="#{cl_image_tag(hiragana.upload, 
   :width => 260, :height => 340)}"%>></i>
</div>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and understood my question. i try it and it works! I just your method `current_user.avatar` to mine `@hiragana.upload`. Tank you. I f I want to iterate do I just remove `@` before `hiragana.upload`?

Comment: Not if the object is created using  the `@` (in your controller) -- which by the way, is the only way to make it available without passing a locals hash.

Comment: I mean I do that in my show view `<span class="popover-trigger fa fa-4x fa-ban "
     data-toggle="popover"
     data-content='<%= cl_image_tag(@hiragana.upload,
        :width => 260, :height => 340) %>'></span>`  and in my index I have to do that                                                                                `<% @hiraganas.each do |hiragana| %>
           <span class="popover-trigger fa fa-4x fa-ban "
     data-toggle="popover"
     data-content='<%= cl_image_tag(hiragana.upload,
        :width => 260, :height => 340) %>'></span>
    <% end %>`

Comment: Yes, the second code you shared is correct, inside the iteration block the `hiragana` indeed should not include the `@`. By the way - Note that `cl_image_tag(hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340)` generates an image tag which requests for the full sized image from Cloudinary and performs the resizing on the client-side (browser-side-resizing). In order to tell Cloudinary to resize the image before delivery, you should also include a crop mode. e.g., `cl_image_tag(hiragana.upload, :width => 260, :height => 340, :crop => :fill)`